# how can inner elements of nested json can be accesed in vuejs

Tags: json, vue.js

[image]

How can 
1)MXN, USD , JPY , KRW , be accessed
2) rates be accessed

In a manner where mxn is selected its rate should be shown
[image]

Comment: You can go over the properties of your outer object and see if it has a property of type "rates" and then iterate over the keys. Use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

Comment: @tomerpacific what would be the syntax for it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you want to use your object in your code, since you haven't posted it, so I am replying to your comment to the best of my ability.

```js
var obj = {
 "time" : "",
  "rates": {
   "MXN": {
     "name": "NAME",
      "rate": "RATE"
    },
    "USD": {
     "name": "NAME",
      "rate": "RATE"
    }
  }
}


function parseRates() {
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty("rates")) {
     var ratesObj = obj.rates;
    
    for(var currency in ratesObj) {
     if (ratesObj.hasOwnProperty(currency)) {
       var curr = ratesObj[currency];
       for(var prop in curr) {
         if (curr.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            var p = curr[prop];
            console.log(p);
              }
            }
          }
    }
     }
}

parseRates();
```

Comment: I want to show in a manner where if usd is selected  from a select option then its rate  will be shown right next to it

Comment: i have added the image in the question ep- suppose USD is selected then usd's rate should be shown next to it

Comment: @Codey - I have responded to your initial question regarding how to parse JSON. You can use what I have shown to fit your demand.